# Save data from Mat Dialog to the parent component

Tags: angular, typescript, dialog

So I have a dialog box and I want to pass the data (true/false boolean) into the parent component. I dont want to console log the result, i need to pass it into a variable in the parent component so i can use it freely.

any idea how I can do this?

this is my parent component :

```
 openDialog( dialogdData : any )
               {
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogExampleComponent, {data : dialogdData});

      dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
          console.log(result);
      });
  }
```

this is my dialog component HTML :

```
<h2 mat-dialog-title>Delete Element?</h2>
<mat-dialog-content>Are you sure you want to delete '{{dialogData.content}}'' from '{{dialogData.column}}'</mat-dialog-content>
<mat-dialog-actions>
    <button mat-button mat-dialog-close mat-dialog-close="true">Delete</button>
    <button mat-button mat-dialog-close mat-dialog-close="false">Cancel</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

and this is my dialog component TS:

```
import { Component, OnInit,Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dialog-example',
  templateUrl: './dialog-example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dialog-example.component.css']
})
export class DialogExampleComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public dialogData : any) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the `close` function of the dialog reference to the component. To do this you will also need to inject the reference. Here are the fixes below.

```
//...
constructor(
  // first inject the dialog reference to the component
  public dialog: MatDialogRef,
  @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public dialogData : any
) { }
//...

// then define a function that will close the dialog with a boolean value
close(value: boolean) {
  return this.dialog.close(value);
}
```

Then we just need to add the click listener to each button and call the close
function.

```
<h2 mat-dialog-title>Delete Element?</h2>
<mat-dialog-content>Are you sure you want to delete '{{dialogData.content}}'' from '{{dialogData.column}}'</mat-dialog-content>
<mat-dialog-actions>
    <button mat-button (click)="close(true)">Delete</button>
    <button mat-button (click)="close(false)">Cancel</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

With this, the subscription will fire with `result` having either a `true` or
`false` value.

**UPDATE**:

If you want to bind this result to a class property, you could do the
following

```
//...
result: Observable<boolean> | undefined;

constructor(
  // first inject the dialog reference to the component
  public dialog: MatDialogRef,
  @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public dialogData : any
) { }

openDialog(dialogdData: any) {
  // you would then assign the property to this afterClosed result
  // since it is a boolean type.
  this.result = this.dialog
    .open(DialogExampleComponent, { data: dialogdData })
    .afterClosed();

  // from here you can use the result property somewhere else like
  // on your UI with an *ngIf or you could also subscribe to it.
}
//...
```

Comment: and then what? if I want to bind the results I recieve to a variable, what do i do exactly ?

Comment: Can you add an implementation of how you are binding currently please